# How can I find who is the parent of a class?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Im working on a game in cocos2d and a class called Player.h.  Its not my game, its a project im reviewing.  It has a method called gotHit which has a call like this:

```
[self.parent processHit];
```

I know its parent is probably a CCLayer, but its a big project so I was just wondering if there is a way to find out which layer class is the actual parent?

Comment: What do you mean "which layer"? You can compare it to likely candidates, but there's no method that magically tells you which of your variables is referencing that layer.

Comment: Well, thats what i wanted to know.  I don't think it would be "magical".  Excel does it by telling you descendants and precedents of cells, I wouldn't think it would be impossible to fathom.  But I understand if Xcode doesn't do it.

Comment: Wait, do you mean what *class* the parent is? As in "is this an instance of a `CCLayer` and not an NSString?"

Comment: @Kevin : ... am assuming OP is actually after an instance of a class. SpriteKite introduces the notion of 'named' nodes. When using cocos2d, i have added a name property to the CCNode class so that i can do just what OP is asking, and i name all my CCSomething objects. Very handy in tight debugging corners, and actually can be put to good functional use. The naming convention is mine, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Cocos2d so I don't know if there's something I'm missing here.

If you want to know what's the parent of a class in XCode you can use the "Assistant Editor".

The first thing you have to do is select the class that you want to find out what the parent is. (Double click the name to highlight it).

Then select the "Assistant Editor". 
And after that select the "Counterparts" menu. (It may say something different, like "Manual")

[image]

After doing this a menu will popup, like this one:

[image]

Select "Superclasses". This will show you the superclasses of the class you have currently selected.

If this doesn't help you, you could find out the parent's class in code, like so:

```
Class class = [self.parent superclass];
NSString *classString = NSStringFromClass(class);
NSLog(@"Parent class: %@", classString);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it is a bit different though, not because of cocos2d, more because of my wording. I want to know which other classes "USE" my Player class in code.

Comment: Well, that's an easy one. If you check the menu, there's an option called "Callers"; this will show you all the clases that are using (calling) your class. Note this option won't be able to tell you when your class is being called using "performSelector..." nor KVC.
Now, if by "USE" you mean what other classes subclass yours, you can check in the menu above the option "Subclasses".

Comment: I clicked on counterparts (with Player selected) and then selected Callers but i get an empty screen. :(

Comment: If you select "Counterparts" it will show you the 'other' part of the class. That is, if you have your *.m file selected, it will show you the *.h it also works the other way around. I don't think that's what you need.

Comment: No, I did select Callers, but even then I just get NO ASSISTANT RESULTS.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how you're selecting the 'Player' class? I use the Assistant Editor all the time and it works like a charm

Comment: Ohh BTW, the "Callers" and "Callees" options are for methods. You can see who calls a specific method by positioning the cursor inside the method you want to examine.